# Find 4k words in a 100k len list of words

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a list of words in a txt file and thousands of words in a list. How can I search for them and add them in a new list if they are found

The words.txt file contain 100k words.
my_list contain 4k words.

Currently I do this.

```py
    my_list = [hello, hi, hey, ho, wow, .....] 

    with open("words.txt") as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    
    words_in_lines = []

    for i in my_list: 
        if i in lines:
            words_in_lines.append(i)
```

This is non ending, it's not executing as there are too many words in the words list.

Comment: There are a variety of syntax errors in this code. I'll suggest some edits. Also in Python, it's conventional practice to use the Ellipsis object to extend a dictionary.

Comment: Where is the dictionary in the code?

Comment: Where are the errors in syntax?

Comment: Apologies, I meant list. You need a `"` after `words.txt` to close the string. The bug in your code is that you're iterating over every character in `words.txt`, not every word.

Comment: Firstly, we need to observe that a file containing 100k words is minuscule, so as first step just gulp it into an array of words `arr` (rather than read it line-by-line). Then if you're not in a terrible rush just compute the  intersection of `arr` and `my_list`. I just tried that in Ruby (`arr & my_list`), first creating an array containing 100k words made up of 5 lowercase letters drawn at random. I then constructed `my_list` from 2k 5-letter random words and 2k words randomly drawn from `arr`. Computing the set intersection (which contained 2,024 unique words) took less than 0.01 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert `my_list` from list to set for faster lookups
2. Instead of looking up words from `my_list` in lines, search for word in `line` inside `my_list`

```py
my_list = set([hello, hi, hey, ho, wow, .....])
words_in_lines = []

with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.strip().split()
        for word in words:
            if word in my_list:
                words_in_lines.append(word)
```

This should have a time complexity of `O(number of words in file)`

Edit: as pointed out by @greybeard, this appproach

1. Does not have the same order of words in `words_in_lines`
2. Modifies `my_list` from list to set
3. Skips the creation of a 100k word list

Comment: A *no fuss* procedure avoiding the unwarranted creation of a 100k word list. You might mention that each of suggestions 1&2 has the order of elements in `words_in_lines` in an order likely different from the code in the question. The code adds using `split()` and modifies `my_list`.

Comment: @greybeard good suggestion, added it to the answer